# How can I solve error timeout in google recaptcha?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, grecaptcha

The recapcha badge looks a little dark like this :

[image]

The error in the console like this :

[image]

This error happened just today. I do not know why. This is weird. Is there a problem with the google recapcha server?

Comment: Time for some debugging. That's so little information we can only say "That sucks, sorry to hear that."

Comment: @tadman What do you mean?

Comment: Unless we have enough information to understand or reproduce the problem, we're just spectators.